# 3d hover effect not works in firefox

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I want to design a 3d hover effect and my code works fine in opera,chrome 
but not work in firefox.
I even try using vendor prefixes but nothing happens. 
Odd part is when I remove anchor tag from my html then code works in all browsers but I
need that anchor tag and with anchor tag effect not works in firefox.

```css
.wrapper {
     width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(35deg) ;
    position: relative ;
    left: calc(50% - 25vw) ;
    top: calc(50% - 25vh) ;
}
.link {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.wrapper * {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper  img {transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.layer {z-index: -1;background-color: #5debb4;       
}
.wrapper:hover img {transform: translateZ(10vmin);
}
.wrapper:hover .layer{transform: translateZ(6vmin);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" class="link">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555919040-66d6d368cfc4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1225&q=80">
            <div class="layer"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is most likely because opera and chrome use -webkit while firfox uses -moz.

Comment: @DatBoiTrump I try both -moz- and -webkit- but nothing happens(problem is not prefixes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `transform-style: preserve-3d;` <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style)</sup> to the link too:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(35deg);
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50% - 25vw);
  top: calc(50% - 25vh);
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.wrapper * {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper img {
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.layer {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #5debb4;
}

.wrapper:hover img {
  transform: translateZ(10vmin);
}

.wrapper:hover .layer {
  transform: translateZ(6vmin);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" class="link">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555919040-66d6d368cfc4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1225&q=80">
    <div class="layer"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: tnx ... can you tell me why my code works in chrome but not in firefox ?

Comment: @AhmadReza well, I would say why the code is not working on chrome because for me the correct behavior is firefox since by default the 3D is not preserved so it seems chrome is make the 3D the default behavior. I don't know exactly why.

Comment: then can you tell why I need two preserve-3d in both .link and .wrapper ? (why just using preserve-3d on .link wont be enough)

Comment: @AhmadReza per my understanding, the preserve-3d affect only direct child and you are  transforming the im and the layer that are child of link thus you need preserve-3d there ... but as you can see this is ambigious, in chrome we only need one that affect all the childs but in firefox we need it on each layer. I cannot tell you which one is correct as it's not very clear in the specification (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#transform-style-property) .. it can also be a bug. I will investigate more with other example to see how it behaves